# while adding dropdown list through javascript add row is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding rows to html through jquery. when i have added "dropdown list" in jquery, add row stopped working. it was perfectly working with input type "text".
Can anyone suggest :
http://jsfiddle.net/znFmc/12/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="page_container">
        <div class="form_container">
            <h3>Add and Delete rows dynamically with textboxes using jQuery:</h3>
            <table id="expense_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sl. No</th>
                        <th>Mode</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="reg_no_01" maxlength="10" required /></td>
                        <td>
                        <select name="mode" maxlength="10" required />
                            <option value="Select"selected>Select</option>
                            <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                            <option value="Car">Car</option>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <input type="button" value="Add Row" id="add_ExpenseRow" />

        </div> <!-- END subject_marks -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <a class="mm" href="http://mediamilan.com/" title="Go to Media Milan.com" target="_blank"></a>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    // GET ID OF last row and increment it by one
    var $lastChar =1, $newRow;
    $get_lastID = function(){
        var $id = $('#expense_table tr:last-child td:first-child input').attr("name");
        $lastChar = parseInt($id.substr($id.length - 2), 10);
        console.log('GET id: ' + $lastChar + ' | $id :'+$id);
        $lastChar = $lastChar + 1;
        $newRow = "<tr> \
                    <td><input type='text' name='reg_no_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /></td> \
                    <td><select name='subjects_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /><option value="Select"selected>Select</option><option value="Auto">Auto</option> <option value="Car">Car</option></td> \
                    <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExpenseRow' /></td> \
                </tr>"
        return $newRow;
    }

    // ***** -- START ADDING NEW ROWS
    $('#add_ExpenseRow').on("click", function(){ 
        if($lastChar <= 9){
            $get_lastID();
            $('#expense_table tbody').append($newRow);
        } else {
            alert("Reached Maximum Rows!");
        };
    });

    $(".del_ExpenseRow").on("click", function(){ 
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        $lastChar = $lastChar-2;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You could open your console...

Comment: You're returning `$newRow` in your function, but you aren't exactly putting it into anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your string isn't formatted properly in here:

```
$newRow = "<tr> \
                <td><input type='text' name='reg_no_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /></td> \
                <td>
                    <select name='subjects_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /> \
                        <option value="Select"selected>Select</option> \
                        <option value="Auto">Auto</option> \
                        <option value="Car">Car</option></td> \
                <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExpenseRow' /></td> \
            </tr>"
```

Replace that with:

```
$newRow = "<tr> \
                <td><input type='text' name='reg_no_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /></td> \
                <td>
                    <select name='subjects_0"+$lastChar+"' maxlength='10' /> \
                        <option value='Select' selected>Select</option> \
                        <option value='Auto'>Auto</option> \
                        <option value='Car'>Car</option></td> \
                <td><input type='button' value='Delete' class='del_ExpenseRow' /></td> \
            </tr>"
```

If you open your browser's console, you'd have seen a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error, notifying you of this issue, and pointing you to that line.

Furthermore, like [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff) suggested, replace:

```
$(".del_ExpenseRow").on("click", function(){
```

With:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del_ExpenseRow", function(){
```

This makes sure that elements added after page load will have the event handlers you want.
(See the [jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for more info about delegated events)

Comment: +1 btw OP should delegate delete buttons click handler like here: http://jsfiddle.net/SqA9a/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks, added it to my answer!

Comment: @ A Wolf. Got it, but still options are not coming in additional rows.